# OpenGl error 1281 after setting gl_fragColor

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I just started programming opengl-es 2.0 and I'm currently struggling to find an issue concerned with setting the color of a wavefront object im drawing (https://pastebin.com/cEvpj8rt). The drawing is working just fine until I start to manipulate the color at which point im being confronted with opengl error 1281 and I'm unable to pinpoint the cause in my code. I've broken down the shader code to what I believe is the bare minimum required for the fragment shader to work:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

To eliminate any additional source of error I am setting the color with a constant value as can be seen above. I doubt the error lies with the simple code above but is concerned with the code in my adapted renderer implementation. (it is based on the renderer that came with a sample from the ar-core github repo. The full code of the initial renderer can be found here: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/java_arcore_hello_ar/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/rendering/ObjectRenderer.java while the adapted version can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/9cmKVnLV) Below you can find an excerpt of the code responsible for setting up and drawing the object. I reckoned the issue to be connected to the texturing which is why I removed the code.

I know its a bit much to ask for help given my lack of understanding on the matter at hand but I'd be glad for any hint/advice at this point. The error occurs after the first draw in the following method:

```
public void draw(float[] cameraView, float[] cameraPerspective) {

    multiplyMM(mModelViewMatrix, 0, cameraView, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    multiplyMM(mModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, cameraPerspective, 0, mModelViewMatrix, 0);

    glUseProgram(mProgram);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBufferId);

    glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionAttribute, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mVerticesBaseAddress);
    glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalAttribute, 3, 
            GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mNormalsBaseAddress);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // Set the ModelViewProjection matrix in the shader.
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewUniform, 1, 
            false, mModelViewMatrix, 0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewProjectionUniform, 1,
            false, mModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionAttribute);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalAttribute);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndexBufferId);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mIndexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionAttribute);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(mNormalAttribute);

    // this is where the error is detected
    OpenGlHelper.checkGLError(TAG, "After draw");
}
```

Here the method which is used for initialization:

```
public void createOnGlThread(Context context) throws IOException {

    InputStream objInputStream = context.getAssets()
                                 .open(OBJ_ASSET_NAME);
    Obj obj = ObjReader.read(objInputStream);
    obj = ObjUtils.convertToRenderable(obj);

    IntBuffer wideIndices = ObjData.getFaceVertexIndices(obj, 3);
    FloatBuffer vertices = ObjData.getVertices(obj);
    FloatBuffer texCoords = ObjData.getTexCoords(obj, 2);
    FloatBuffer normals = ObjData.getNormals(obj);

    ShortBuffer indices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2 * wideIndices.limit())
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();

    while (wideIndices.hasRemaining()) {
        indices.put((short) wideIndices.get());
    }
    indices.rewind();

    int[] buffers = new int[2];
    glGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0);
    mVertexBufferId = buffers[0];
    mIndexBufferId = buffers[1];

    // Load vertex buffer
    mVerticesBaseAddress = 0;
    mTexCoordsBaseAddress = mVerticesBaseAddress + 4 * vertices.limit();
    mNormalsBaseAddress = mTexCoordsBaseAddress + 4 * texCoords.limit();
    final int totalBytes = mNormalsBaseAddress + 4 * normals.limit();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, totalBytes, null, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVerticesBaseAddress,
            4 * vertices.limit(), vertices);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mTexCoordsBaseAddress, 
            4 * texCoords.limit(), texCoords);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mNormalsBaseAddress, 
            4 * normals.limit(), normals);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // Load index buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndexBufferId);
    mIndexCount = indices.limit();
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * mIndexCount, 
                 indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    OpenGlHelper.checkGLError(TAG, "OBJ buffer load");

    mProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(mProgram, OpenGlHelper.loadGLShader(TAG, context,
            GL_VERTEX_SHADER, R.raw.sphere_vertex));
    glAttachShader(mProgram, OpenGlHelper.loadGLShader(TAG, context,
            GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, R.raw.sphere_fragment));
    glLinkProgram(mProgram);
    glUseProgram(mProgram);

    OpenGlHelper.checkGLError(TAG, "Program creation");

    mModelViewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_ModelView");
    mModelViewProjectionUniform =
            glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_ModelViewProjection");
    mPositionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Position");
    mNormalAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Normal");

    OpenGlHelper.checkGLError(TAG, "Program parameters");

    setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is in the shader? Error 1281 is `GL_INVALID_VALUE` so error is in some of the java code.

Comment: Basically stick "glGetError()" calls after every OpenGL ES function call you make - that will tell you which one is going wrong (just don't leave these in when you release your program - they have a cost).

Comment: @Reaper Idont think the problem lies with the shader. Maybe I wasnt clear enough.

Comment: @solidpixel We have a winner. Please excuse the wordplay but as the name says this is a "solid" advice. Thanks a bunch.